# Optional variable - variable might not be initialized

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Is this the correct way to  use and initialize the Optional variables .. I get an error "variable might not be initialized " on all these variables when I call calculateAnnualCalculationTotal ..I want to use these variables in the annualCalculationSummaryDto if the insurance.product isn't abc or def otherwise those three fields that am trying to set in the annualCalculationSummaryDto should remain null ..

```
                 Optional<CalculatedPaymentsDto> calculatedPayments  ;
        Optional<PaidPaymentsDTO> paidPayments  ;
        Optional<CreatePaymentResponseDto> payment ;

        if (!insurance.getProduct().equalsIgnoreCase("abc") && !insurance.getProduct().equalsIgnoreCase("def")) {

            int totalAnnualCalculationSum = calculateAnnualCalculationTotal(insurance, requestDto.getAnnualCalculationYear(), calculatedPayments, paidPayments);
            payment = Optional.ofNullable(createPayment(getCreatePaymentRequestDto(insurance, calculatedPayments.get(), totalAnnualCalculationSum, requestDto.getAnnualCalculationYear())));
        }

        AnnualCalculationSummaryDto annualCalculationSummaryDto = new AnnualCalculationSummaryDto();
        if(calculatedPayments.isPresent() && paidPayments.isPresent() && payment.isPresent()){
            annualCalculationSummaryDto.setCalculatedPaymentsDto(calculatedPayments.get());
            annualCalculationSummaryDto.setPaidPaymentsDTO(paidPayments.get());
            annualCalculationSummaryDto.setPayments(payment.get());
        }
     annualCalculationSummaryDto.setParam1(inr.getProduct());
     annualCalculationSummaryDto.setParam2(requestDto.getTotal());
     annualCalculationSummaryRepository.save(annualCalculationSummaryDto);
```

.............
.............
..............

```
private int calculateAnnualCalculationTotal (Insurance insurance , int year , Optional<CalculatedPaymentsDto> calculatedPayments , Optional<PaidPaymentsDTO> paidPayments) {

        calculatedPayments = Optional.ofNullable(paymentService.getCalculatedPayments(insurance.getId(), year));

        paidPayments = Optional.ofNullable(paymentService.getPaidPayments(insurance.getInsuranceYears(), year));
       totalSum = calculatedPayments.get().getParam1()+ paidPayments.get().getParam2();
.....
}
```

Or is there a better way to write this ..

Comment: *Or is there a better way to write this* - it is. don't use Optional for this

Comment: Java has no pass-by-reference, so you can’t abuse the method’s parameters as return values. You are trying to pass uninitialized variables to the method, which does not work and within the method, you are assigning values to parameter variables, which has no effect to the caller.

Comment: @Eugene , Optional.empty() did the trick .. but you say that a better way is to not use Optional ? .. how do you propose I do that in my code ? .. Only if !insurance.getProduct().equalsIgnoreCase("abc") && !insurance.getProduct().equalsIgnoreCase("def")) I want to set those optional variable and use it in annualCalculationSummaryDto.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the initialization of `payment` inside an `if`-clause, it's not guaranteed to be initialized.
To initialize an Optional as `null` use `Optional<T> myOptional = Optional.empty();`

A nice [article about Optionals](https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-optional-tutorial/)